# template: unresolved variable or type $ctrl

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm, webstorm, angularjs-components

How to tell PhpStorm/WebStorm that `$ctrl` in a template is known and also help it decide the controller it belongs to (maybe using jsdoc)?

I create components in this manner in Angular 1.5:

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .component('myComponent', {
        templateUrl: "my.component.html",
        controller : [
            MyComponentController
        ]
    });
```

`ControllerAs` didn't help...

HTML snippet of where the problem appears (`$ctrl.*`):

```
<div class="entity-summary clear" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleInfo()"> 
  <div class="entity-col">
    {{$ctrl.entity.id}}
  </div>
  <div class="entity-col">
    {{$ctrl.entity.host}}
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Normally the IDE should know this. What does the controller usage in template look like? Code snippets would be helpful

Comment: @lena `<div class="entity-summary clear" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleInfo()">
  <div class="entity-col">{{$ctrl.entity.id}}</div>
  <div class="entity-col">{{$ctrl.entity.host}}</div>
</div>` here it is. (code snippets don't work in comments :( ) Your help will much appreciated. :)

Comment: yes that's the code snippet. I dared to update the question with your piece @doroshko. ;)

Comment: hope that @lena could help us

Comment: At Jetbrains they've managed to get some time for AngularJS maintenance. Finally the fix is in 2018.3 EAP! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26886

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Angular 1.5 components are not yet fully supported, please follow [WEB-20339](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20339) for updates

Comment: the fix is in 2018.3 EAP! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26886

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid most of the noise by (mis)using ng-init="$ctrl=$ctrl":

```
<div ng-init="$ctrl=$ctrl"         
     ng-click="$ctrl.toggleInfo()"
     class="entity-summary clear" > 
  <div class="entity-col">
    {{$ctrl.entity.id}}
  </div>
  <div class="entity-col">
    {{$ctrl.entity.host}}
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, yar1. It works but I'd better prefer not to put such a hack to the code although it solves the IDE issue.

Comment: Agreed. Just a temp solution until they fix WebStorm to work well with Angular 1.5 components (and an easy one to remove once they do).

Comment: ...and when using ***TypeScript with AngularJS***, you can write the type hint between script tags `<script>/** @var {ComponentClass} $ctrl */</script>` to have full typed autocomplete within the IDE. <script> tags in templates are not executed by default.

Comment: Or an alternative that doesn't seem to pollute the global namespace: `<script>
    /** @type {OrderComponent} */
    let $ctrl;
</script>`

Answer (score 2):

I found a not that bad workaround.

**Condition**

You have to use at least ES2016.

If you have a component like this:

```
export class MyComponent {

}

export const MyComponentController = {
  controller: MyComponent,
  templateUrl: require('./my-component.html')
};
```

you can simple add the following line:

```
module.$ctrl = MyComponent;
```

Then WebStorm is able to resolve `$ctrl` in the template. The intellisense/autocomplete is unfortunately still not working .

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just realized this wasnt about removing the error/warning but leaving this answer anyway:

I removed the warning in Editor > Inpections > Unresolved Javascript variable for everything but javascript sources scope (which i have set up for my project). Its a bit of a "shotgun solution" but i can live without this check in html files...